# UPS and PDU options for NEMA L6-30P

Tags: electrical-power, ups, power-distribution-unit

I have to say I don't know enough about supplying power to a rack. So here goes:

This is for a room that will host network equipment (and maybe a server), in an office.

Room has: some 120VAC outlets; one 30A, 250VAC outlet.

This is in the USA.

Trying to buy a UPS and PDU set such that I can use the 30A NEMA L6-30P wall outlet; the 30A/250VAC outlet is right next to the rack.

I can only find PDUs -- i.e. not UPSes -- that have an L6-30P input and have NEMA 5-15 12VAC Outputs.

Am I looking for the wrong thing? Previous experience at datacenters has had me plugging the PDU directly into the provided power outlet; but that datacenter had conditioned power and explicitely prohibited colo customers from bringing their own UPSes.

The other DC experience had us plug the UPS into the power but we had to get a specially made whip adapter to allow the UPS to plug into the NEMA L6-30P cabinet outlet.

What is the proper set of UPS and PDU such that I can use the 30A outlet I have in this room? without spending $5000US.

**Edit -- spoke with APC**

I spoke with a rep at APC and he said that I need a step-down transformer. **however**, he says that it needs to be a step-down that is incorporated into a larger UPS. And that I cannot plug a 120VAC UPS into a step-down transformer directly.

This doesn't sound right to me, frankly. Where can I find out more information about using a step-down transformer and whether I can plug a 120VAC UPS into a 250VAC->120VAC step-down transformer?